# What is libc-bin?

Tags: apt

When updating some packages with `sudo apt update`, I've noticed a line that appears every time:

```
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.3) ...
```

...And **I'd like to know what libc-bin** is and what it does.

Comment: Are you asking what processing triggers is? You [asked that in a different question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1386593/what-does-it-mean-to-process-triggers). Or are you asking what that package is? If the latter, you should [see the Ubuntu package repo](https://packages.ubuntu.com/impish/libc-bin).

Comment: @cocomac oh, sorry for not clarifying. No, I'm asking what libc-bin is, not processing triggers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A number of programs for Linux, among them the kernel itself, are written in the [programming language C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_(programming_language)) (parts of the kernel are written in Assembler, but the general idea holds ;) ). Implementations of C typically come with a version of the [C standard library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library), which provides a lot of the commonly used functionality for C. This C standard library is also called `libc`. There are several implementations of the `libc`, among them the [GNU C library or glibc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glibc), [musl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musl) or the [BSD libc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library#BSD_libc).

[`libc-bin`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal-updates/libc-bin), in turn, is a collection of helper programs, so called binary tools, that work in conjunction with `libc`. Those tools can read from the system configuration, configure dependencies from shared libraries and other things. If during the installation of a package one of those `libc` tools needs to do something, it gets `trigger`ed to do it.