# What does it mean to "process triggers"?

Tags: apt

When I update things with apt (`sudo apt update` etc), I notice that a lot of lines start with "`processing triggers...`" and I'd like to know what it means or what it does.

Comment: See [this page](https://wiki.debian.org/DpkgTriggers) on the Debian wiki